# React Node node not found while testing FaC with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I'm building an app in React Native. We recently started using TypeScript in the app and my task is to migrate the unit tests. There is one test that is miracously failing.

The app has a `<LoginForm />` that uses [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik).

```ts
//... imports

export interface FormValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface Props {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}

export default class LoginForm extends Component<Props, object> {
  handleSubmit = (values: FormValues, formikBag: FormikActions<FormValues>) => {
    // ... api calls and stuff
  };

  renderForm = ({
    values,
    handleSubmit,
    setFieldValue,
    touched,
    errors,
    setFieldTouched,
    isValid,
    isSubmitting
  }: FormikProps<FormValues>) => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      // ... two inputs and a button
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values: FormValues, formikBag: FormikActions<FormValues>) =>
          this.handleSubmit(values, formikBag)
        }
        validationSchema={<some_schema>}
        render={(formikBag: FormikProps<FormValues>) => this.renderForm(formikBag)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the unit test looks for the Function as Child `renderForm()`:

```ts
describe("renderForm", () => {
  let formWrapper: ShallowWrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    let formikBagMock: any = {
      values: { email: "Test Email", password: "testpassword" },
      handleSubmit: jest.fn(),
      setFieldValue: jest.fn(),
      errors: { email: "Test error", password: "" },
      touched: { email: true, password: false },
      setFieldTouched: jest.fn(),
      isValid: false,
      isSubmitting: false
    };
    formWrapper = shallow(wrapper.instance().renderForm(formikBagMock));
  });

  it("should render a <View />", () => {
    expect(formWrapper.find("View")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("should render two <Input />", () => {
    expect(formWrapper.find("Input")).toHaveLength(2);
  });

  it("should render a <Button />", () => {
    expect(formWrapper.find("Button")).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  describe("styling", () => {
    it("should give the <View /> the 'container' style", () => {
      expect(formWrapper.find(View).prop("style")).toEqual(styles.container);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that, while this test was passing in `.js` it is failing in `.tsx`.

```ts
The error thrown looks like this:

 ● LoginForm › rendering › renderForm › should render a <Button />

    expect(received).toHaveLength(length)

    Expected value to have length:
      1
    Received:
      {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): {Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular], Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <Component style={{"alignItems": "center", "flex": 1, "justifyContent": "space-evenly"}}><Input autoCapitalize="none" editable={true} errorMessage="Test error" keyboardType="email-address" onBlur={[Function onBlur]} onChangeText={[Function onChangeText]} placeholder="Email address" value="Test Email" /><Input autoCapitalize="none" editable={true} onBlur={[Function onBlur]} onChangeText={[Function onChangeText]} placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} value="testpassword" /><Button TouchableComponent={[Function anonymous]} buttonStyle={{"backgroundColor": "#DC4F19"}} clear={false} containerStyle={{"paddingVertical": 5, "width": "33%"}} disabled={true} disabledStyle={{"backgroundColor": "#DC4F19", "opacity": 0.3}} disabledTitleStyle={{"color": "white"}} iconRight={false} loading={false} loadingProps={{"color": "white", "size": "large"}} onPress={[Function mockConstructor]} raised={false} title="Log In" titleStyle={{"color": "white"}} /></Component>, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__node__): {"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "function", "props": {"children": [Function anonymous]}, "ref": null, "rendered": [Function anonymous], "type": {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.context), "Consumer": [Circular], "Provider": {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.provider), "_context": [Circular]}, "_calculateChangedBits": null, "_currentRenderer": null, "_currentRenderer2": null, "_currentValue": false, "_currentValue2": false, "unstable_read": [Function bound readContext]}}, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [{"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "function", "props": {"children": [Function anonymous]}, "ref": null, "rendered": [Function anonymous], "type": {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.context), "Consumer": [Circular], "Provider": {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.provider), "_context": [Circular]}, "_calculateChangedBits": null, "_currentRenderer": null, "_currentRenderer2": null, "_currentValue": false, "_currentValue2": false, "unstable_read": [Function bound readContext]}}], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}, "attachTo": undefined, "hydrateIn": undefined}}, Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): null, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__node__): undefined, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}, "attachTo": undefined, "hydrateIn": undefined}}
    received.length:
      0

      61 |
      62 |       it("should render a <Button />", () => {
    > 63 |         expect(formWrapper.find("Button")).toHaveLength(1);
         |                                            ^
      64 |       });
      65 |
      66 |       describe("styling", () => {
```

How can it be, that Enzyme suddenly does not find the node anymore? I even tried importing the components `View`, `Button` and `Input` directly and passing that to `find()` instead of the strings, but it doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you compile test file from `typescript` into `js`, and show here? I feel like it can help to find the issue

Comment: also, maybe it helps if you explicitly set the returned type:  `renderForm(...): ReactNode => ...`

Comment: @Alex I don't understand your request. The part where it says `describe("renderForm", ...` is already the file? The only TypeScript-y thing there is the `ShallowWrapper` type. The rest is verbatim what we used in the JS file.

Comment: @Alex adding `ReactNode` as a return value breaks the test, because `ShallowWrapper` expects a `ReactElement<any>` (which I added now as the return value).

Comment: this is not an answer. 1- using `typescript` in `react-native` project make it just like spaghetti. 2- these type of questions need two things. great bounties and a reproduction repository to test.

Comment: What is your ts-jest configs? I was tried and I'm using entire react project with Typescript in production.
In my experience, kinda this problems almost related into configuration of test framework.
Typescript with js test framework is hell. Not only jest, but mocha does.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `formWrapper.debug()` in the `.js` and `.tsx` files to see what's different.

Since you're using [`Shallow Rendering`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) you might need to [`dive()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to hit `Button`. Use `console.log(formWrapper.debug())` to see what is rendered.

If only `View` is rendered, try: `expect(formWrapper.dive().find("Button")).toHaveLength(1)`